# How can I get all cube and all dimensions and all measures in one DataBase in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, olap, cube, ssas-2008

I use sql server 2008 r2.

I use SSAS service and i have one database that named `GAC`.

in my database exist 10 cube and in each cube exist several measures and dimensions

I need get all cubes, measure and dimensions with one select.

how can I do this?

in other hands, i need access to data definitions table or structure like sys.tables and sys.columns and sys.type and etc.

i need one select that it can query all data from SSAS database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS schema request without restricting cube or dimension.

Answer (score 1):

i finded this :

```
select 
    cube_name,
    measuregroup_name,
    measure_name,
    expression
from $system.dbschema_measures
```